# Will a Mishiki Pueblo Mountain 20 in frame hold my weight. I go about 330

Tags: safety, weight

I weigh about 330  ...

Will a Mishiki Pueblo Mountain Bike 20 inch frame will hold my weight?

Comment: 330 as in lbs or kg?

Comment: Frame will. Wheels and axles will be the weak point.

Comment: At that weight the suspension fork will likely bottom out as soon as you get on it.  I wouldn't recommend a suspension bike unless there's a lock-out.

Answer (score 3):

First congratulations for getting back on a bike. As others have stated the typical weak point will be the axles and wheels. I would recommend having the wheel bearings serviced by your local bike shop. Ask them to check the spoke tension as well. I've seen quite a few low end wheels with poorly adjusted bearings and almost no grease in the hub. I would then run the tire pressure to the max spec on the tire sidewall. Even then they are likely only suitable for pavement or bike path use. If wheel problems occur consider investing in a set of wheels designed for a tandem bike. They are capable of supporting 2 adults. While they will cost more then your current bike you can use them on your next bike when you upgrade. Another option is a used LandRider auto shift. They are frequently listed on Craigs List for under $200 in my area. They are rated for 350 pounds

Comment: +1 (Although the suggestion for a LandRider auto shift almost earns you a -1 I rode once, I would not wish one on my worst enemy).